# Divide Null by a number in SQL

Tags: sql, null, divide

I got a question: if I have a `Product` table in SQL which has columns `Product ID`, `TotalPrice`, `NumberOfUnits`

Now I need to calculate the `unitPrice` of the product.

This can be calculated by dividing the `TotalPrice` by `NumberOfUnits`.

Now the question is: if the `totalPrice` is `Null` and `NumberOfUnits` is 45.

What will the output be?

```
Select 
    ProductID,
    (TotalPrice / NumberOfUnits) as UnitPrice 
from ProductTable
```

What will be the output?

And if the answer is null, how can we handle this?

Comment: **(a)** have you tried yourself!?!?!? **(b)** the output will be `NULL` - any operation with `NULL` results in `NULL` - what's the problem with that??

Comment: Try it and find out?  (Spoiler: it's `Null`)  As for how to handle it, an option is that you can wrap it in `IsNull(TotalPrice, 0)` to default it to 0.  But that's completely up to you how you wish to handle that.

Comment: How do you _want_ to handle it?  What does a `TotalPrice` of null mean?

Comment: You also want to check for your `NumberofUnits` is not equal to `Zero` else you will get a `divide by zero` exception, one fine day.

Comment: @SoulTrain: except when using MySQL which defies the law of mathematics and allows a division by zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null = NULL.

```
SELECT NULL / 45
```

Result

```
Column1
NULL
```

Handling would be...

```
SELECT IsNull(NULL, 0) / 45
```

Result

```
Column1
0
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Null/45 = NULL
2. anynumber/null = null

Your table structure is incorrect, you need to create the table in a way that it cannot accept null for price as well as quantity.

Rest will have a big discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go:

```
Select ProductID
,(isnull(TotalPrice, 0)/NumberOfUnits) as UnitPrice
from ProductTable
```

In this instance, `isnull(totalPrice, 0)` replaces any `NULL` values with `0`.

Comment: My company at least prefers to price its products above `0` :)